# Optimization of Thompson Construction of an NFA

Tags: automata, finite-automata

[image]

I would like to ask under which circumstances can these optimizations be used,supposed that they are part of a bigger NFA and when can they lead to an error ??

Answer (score 1):

In general these reductions are OK when there are no other edges incident to the edges you are contracting. Whenever there are other edges there can be unexpected paths.

I do not know of a good characterization when they can be used. If such an improvement would have been obvious, I think Thompson would have included it.

[image]